# Multi Process in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-multiprocessing, django-serializer

I am creating rest API using Django rest framework.
while calling an api i want to execute another process without effecting the actual api.
i created like this

```
def proces_add(request):
emp=Employee.objects.get(EmployeeId=request.data.get("Emp"))
 result = {
            'Status': success,
            'Message': 'process called',
            'Employee': emp.EmployeeId
        }
        p = Process(target=proce_new, args=(emp.EmployeeId,))
        p.start()
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


def proce_new(emp):
    try:
        device = Device.objects.all()
        for val in device:
            div = val.Device.DeviceCode
            sync = Synchronization(
                Device=div,
                SyncType=1
            )
            sync.save()
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(repr(ex))
```

but data is not getting saved.. what is the issue
How can I make it working well? I am using multiprocess at the first time .. is it correct?

any body can give me any idea or what is the issue with my code

Comment: Couple of things. Based on `proce_new` function i guess it is expecting `Employee` object, and the args passed seem to be `EmployeeId`. Also `proce_new` function seems to take only one argument but in `Process` there are 2 arguments being passed. Please try updating this and check if it works.

Comment: @Kashyap KN i updated.. but not working